# After upgrading my project to Angular 8 from Angular 7.2, compile time increased 3 times. How can I fix it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I upgraded my project to Angular 8 version. While upgrading process, I haven't  met any error. But the compile time increased 3 time without any error. At least, How can I get the old compile time?

** P.S.: There is a bug cause to this problem. The issue related to this bug** https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13734

```
Last Compile Before Angular 8  (with Angular 7.2)
Time: 1382.536ms -> main.cf29a89468d732f3f363.js (main) 12.4 MB 

First Compile After Upgrading to Angular 8
Time: 6379.317ms -> main.da4147c72278bc767ee4.js (main) 12.3 MB 

Second Compile After Upgrading to Angular 8 and After restart PC 
Time: 3147.254ms -> main.da4147c72278bc767ee4.js (main) 12.3 MB
```

tsconfig.json

```
    {
     "compileOnSave": false,
     "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "",
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "mapRoot": "./",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../__dist_cli",
        "sourceMap": true, 
        "target": "es5 ", 
        "module": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "typings/custom"
        ]
    }
```

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.0
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0
```

Comment: retrace steps to see if anything was missed https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0

Comment: I have retraced the upgrade protocol. There is no missing point. Additionally I haven't met any error during production compile. Then the compiled code runs without any error.

Comment: I reverted back to 7 yesterday after upgrading, I figured differential package loading wasn't worth the teething problems. Not interested in the beta features.

Comment: I have been working on upgrading to angular 8 for two days. The project actually does not have too much dependency, which may be likely to be the problem. There are only hammerjs and quill. I started use angular 7.2 again for a temporary solution. I opened a github issue related to this problem. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14604

Comment: @Ali Altun any luck since posting?

Comment: @Matt Thurston There will be an upgrade in angular-cli 8.0.x to solve this problem according to Alan Agius who is angular-cli team member. For temporary solution, I started to use angular 7.2 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved in the updated version of the Angular CLI (^8.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try building package with command

```
ng build --es5BrowserSupport=false
```

This will produce package for only modern browsers.
This will help you to figure out whether the differential loading packaging building took additional time.

Comment: The compiler message: Option "es5BrowserSupport" is deprecated:

Comment: I have added  "browserslist": [ "> 1%" ] to package.json instead of es5BrowserSupport=false. After this update, there is no significant reduction
in the file size and compile time.